# java.lang.numberFormatException: Invalid int "_id"

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am trying add data to a table named as User Table. It has two columns Task and SubTask. Task should hold the _id value of Task Table and SubTask should hold the _id value of SubTask table. Hence I have referenced those two columns as foreign keys to this table. Now I am not able to insert values to this table. I ma getting the above stated exception. Please can anyone let me know what must be done to overcome this. All suggestions are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Schema of UserTable:

```
public static final String CREATE_TABLE_USER = " CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USER + " ( " + UID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            TASK + " INTEGER, " + SUB_TASK + " INTEGER, " + " FOREIGN KEY (" + TASK + ") REFERENCES " + TABLE_NAME + " (" + UID + " )" +
            " FOREIGN KEY (" + SUB_TASK + ") REFERENCES " + TABLE_NAME_CHILD + " (" + UIDCHILD + ") );";
```

Database code written for insert operation:

```
public long addTaskPosition( int task_number, int sub_task_number) {

        db = helper.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

        contentValues.put(SQLiteHelper.TASK, task_number);
        contentValues.put(SQLiteHelper.SUB_TASK, sub_task_number);
        id2 = db.insert(SQLiteHelper.TABLE_USER, null, contentValues);


        Log.d("PaNa", "The value of Id is " + id);

        db.close();
        return id2;


    }
```

Code written in the activity to set the values for the db:

```
 int taskNumber = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(SQLiteHelper.UID));
        Log.d("Pana" ,  "The value of taskNumber is " +taskNumber);
        int subTaskNumber = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(SQLiteHelper.UIDCHILD.toString()));


        long id2 = sqliteHelper.addTaskPosition(taskNumber, subTaskNumber);

        if (id2 < 0) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Insert Unsuccessful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Insert Successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

Adb Trace:

```
 Process: com.ms.t.tms, PID: 1835
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4007)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4002)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "_id"
            at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
            at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:410)
            at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:367)
            at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:334)
            at com.ms.t.tms.InsertSubTaskActivity.addUser(InsertSubTaskActivity.java:496)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4002)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Please let me know what must be done to overcome this. I am new to android. Please do help me. Thank you.

Comment: post your logcat also

Comment: sorry will post it now. Forgot.

Comment: i think SQLiteHelper.UID is giving you the column name(_id) not the column value ,are you sure you are getting column value

Comment: Exactly. NO I am getting the column name. I need column value. What change should I make in order to get column value?

Comment: what is SQLiteHelper.UID?

Comment: _id column name of Task Table, SQLiteHelper.UIDCHILD is _id column name of Subtask table.

Comment: I need the value present in that _id column of both tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want value for your SQLiteHelper.UIDCHILD and SQLiteHelper.UID you can execute rewquery on the respective table,and iterate it using:

```
   ArrayList uid=new ArrayList<Integer>();
   Cursor cur=db.rawQuery("SELECT _id FROM yourtablename",null);
   if (cur.getCount() > 0) 
      {
      cur.moveToFirst();
       do 
        {
        uid.add(cur.getInt(0));
        }
      while (cur.moveToNext());
     cur.close();
      }
```

and same for the other.You can pass this arraylist to a acitivity via an intent like this

```
Intent intent=new Intent(Activity_context,youractivity_class);
intent.putStringArrayListExtra("uid",uid);
Activity_context.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Ok. now if have to use the  values to insert them into another table, should I use intent.putExtra and then retrieve the value by intent.get Extra?

Comment: I need to use these value in activity.

Comment: i would say store these values in arraylist and then pass this arraylist via intent and get the values as you want and use them,if you want i can edit my answer

Comment: Yes please. it will help me to a great extent.